# How do I loop through a range plus an integer?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find(What:="123")
    'Let's assume Rng is A2 here, but it could be anything within the Range.
    count = 5
    'Let's assume count is 5 here, but it can be anything from 2 to 10.
    'Here I want to loop from A2 to A(2+5)
End Sub
```

`Rng` and `count` will both change because I have another loop outside of this. `Rng` will only be one cell. Does anyone know how to do this? Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it like that

```
   Sub test1()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    'Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    Const COL = 1
    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, COL)
    count = 5
    'Here I want to loop from A2 to A(2+5)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To count
        Debug.Print Rng.Cells(i, COL).Address
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Update** According to your edit you might need sth. like that

```
Sub test1()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

    Dim col As Long
    col = Rng.Column
    count = 5
    'Here I want to loop from A2 to A(2+5)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To count
        Debug.Print Rng.Cells(i, col).Address
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I googled how to convert between Range and cells. This could totally work! Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post according to your edit of your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()
    'Dim Rng As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim x As Long, i As Long

    'Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    count = 5
    'Here I want to loop from A2 to A(2+5)
    x = 10
    For i = 1 To x
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("A" & (2 + i * 5)) = x  'or whatever You want to do
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't express myself clearly. I edited the post hopefully it make more sense now. Thx!